# Why does it open the file in the editor instead of running it?

Tags: python, windows, file, tkinter, operating-system

so I've been working on a Tkinter project to get better at Python, and I've made a number guesser game (number_guesser.py) and now im trying to make a menu window with buttons. Depending on what button you click it will forward you to the specified game window and close the main window.

This is my current code in the main.py file (menu window)

```
import os
import random

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Minigames")
main.geometry("450x400")
main.resizable(width= False, height= False)

def forwardtoo():
    os.startfile('C:/Users/Windows/PycharmProjects/GUI with minigames/number_guesser.py')
    main.destroy()




b1 = tk.Button(main, text="Number Guesser", command=forwardtoo)
b1.place(x = 170, y = 250)

main.mainloop()
```

So ive seen people say to do this `os.startfile(path[, operation][, arguments][, cwd][, show_cmd])` but the problem with that is that I have no idea what i have to put in operation, arguments, cwd and show cwd. Im sorry if this is a simple solution, but im new to Python and still learning it.

I appreciate every help :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, based on the button clicked You want to run specific game? If so, the best way to do this is to import some function responsible for running the game and then run in instead of executing the entire script. So for example:

Let's assume that file number_guesser.py looks like this:

```
def guesser_logic():
    # some_logic
    ...

def run():
    guesser_logic()
```

Then in the file containing button actions (let's name it main.py) You could do:

```
import os
import random

from number_guesser import run

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Minigames")
main.geometry("450x400")
main.resizable(width= False, height= False)

def forwardtoo():
    run()
    main.destroy()

b1 = tk.Button(main, text="Number Guesser", command=forwardtoo)
b1.place(x = 170, y = 250)

main.mainloop()
```

Notice the extra import and the change I made.

Answer (score 0):

from the doc: "When another operation is given, it must be a “command verb” that specifies what should be done with the file. Common verbs documented by Microsoft are 'print' and 'edit' (to be used on files) as well as 'explore' and 'find' (to be used on directories).".
For your purpose you can leave it empty.

However, I'd recommend you not to use os.startfile.
I guess you're program is in another file, for exemple "play_game.py", with a function called "start_game()"
If it is in your current directory, then you can import it like so:

```
import os
import random
import play_game

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Minigames")
main.geometry("450x400")
main.resizable(width= False, height= False)

def forwardtoo():
    play_game.start_game()
    main.destroy()




b1 = tk.Button(main, text="Number Guesser", command=forwardtoo)
b1.place(x = 170, y = 250)

main.mainloop()
```

Every function in the file can now be called with `play_game.NAME_OF_THE_FUNCTION()`
You should also create an input textfields so that the user can play with the inputs he wants, you'd need to store the inputs and then create a button linked to start_game() which would retrieve the user's input.
Hope this was clear and it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, code is not working because you are missing tkinter import.**
Following code will start the game you specify in os.startfile, in code I modfyed for you it will start calculator app. You can add more buttons and more functions to start more games, or you can do dropdown menu with single button to start what you select under dropdown menu.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Minigames")
main.geometry("450x400")
main.resizable(width= False, height= False)


def forwardtoo():
    os.startfile('C:/Users/my/Desktop/programming/tkinter/calculator.py')
    main.destroy()


b1 = Button(main, text="Number Guesser", command=forwardtoo)
b1.place(x=170, y=250)

main.mainloop()
```

If you don't want to call diferent scripts from your computer using os module, you can make function inside current code that will hold game logic, or make class that will contain game, choice is yours.

Comment: The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools." and most developers agree with that. So in this case fixing the missing import with `import tkinter as tk` would have been the better option.

Comment: I agree, it can be done as you said, correct. I just wanted to demonstrate that code is missing tkinter module, and I corrected my mistake in the code. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

As `os.startfile()` will use the registered program associated to file extension `.py`.  For your case, the registered program is the editor.

I would suggest to use `subprocess.Popen()` instead:

```py
import sys
import subprocess
...

def forwardtoo():
    main.destroy()
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'C:/Users/Windows/PycharmProjects/GUI with minigames/number_guesser.py'])

...
```